# How to access a SharedPreferences field?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-context, listpreference

I'm trying to access a SharedPreferences field declared in an activity from a SAX parser class.

I tried using getDefaultSharedPreferences(context), but I was unable to find a context to pass as an argument for this method as the SAX parser doesn't extend Activity.

How can I access this field ?

Now, let's suppose I managed to do this. I have a second problem here : my SharedPreferences field is declared in an Activity (a class extending PreferenceActivity actually). In this SharedPreferences field, I can store boolean values from two lists of checkboxes, standing for two lists of multi choice preferences.

I need to know which value of these lists of preferences are "true". How can I do that ?

Here is my code :- Pref.java

```
public class Pref extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
static SharedPreferences pref;

public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

    pref = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    int c = pref.getInt("numRun",0);
    c++;
    pref.edit().putInt("numRun",c).commit();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

I think I need first to access to pref, but then I have two multi choices preferences lists. How to get values from these lists?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

username = prefs.getString("username","");

password = prefs.getString("password","");
```